# Best way to implement UIToolbar with UITextField above keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitextfield, uitoolbar

What is the best way to have a `UIToolbar` with a `UITextField` appear above the keyboard ?

In particular, I'm looking for a way to implement this in iOS 6.

The basic functionality I am trying to achieve is similar to iOS SMS app except the keyboard would appear by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Either adding a toolbar to your storyboard and add an outlet to it, or add the toolbar to a xib file then use InputAccessoryView of text field you want to add the toolbar to it
e.g.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardToolbar" owner:self options:nil];
[textField setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
```

[image]